# Use RankX function to calculate date rank per Fiscal Year per Entity ID

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I would like to use the `RankX` function (to use the Dense feature for ties) in order to rank the dates in a table per two columns: `Fiscal Year` and `Entity ID`.

(I guess it may be easier to concatenate the two columns and just sort by that but I'm having issues with my formula still)

Below is my sample data:

[image: Sample]

My invalid dax formula which returns all 1's is:

```
Fiscal Purchase Index = 
VAR a = 'Purchases'[Purchase_Date]
VAR b = 'Purchases'[Entity_ID]
var c = 'Purchases'[FISCAL_YEAR]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        RANKX ('Purchases', a,,1,Dense ),
        FILTER (all('Purchases'), 
            'Purchases'[Entity_ID] = b &&
            'Purchases'[FISCAL_YEAR] = c
        )
    )
```

Any help in fixing the rank formula would be very much appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following dax formula:

```
Fiscal Purchase Index = 

VAR __entity = 'Purchases'[Entity ID]
var __year = 'Purchases'[FISCAL YEAR]
var __table = FILTER ( all('Purchases'), 'Purchases'[Entity ID] = __entity && 'Purchases'[FISCAL YEAR] = __year )

var __result = 
RANKX(__table, Purchases[Date] ,, 1, Dense) 

RETURN __result
```

Hope it helps.